# PHP Mail adding CC

Tags: php, email

I have this PHP Mail Function:

```
if(!function_exists("sendemail"))
{
    function sendemail($email_to,$email_from,$email_subject,$email_body,$email_replyto)
    {
        if(filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

            $from = $email_from;
            $to = $email_to;
            $subject = $email_subject;
            $body = $email_body;

            $host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
            $username = "sending@domain.co.uk";
            $password = "*******";

            $headers = array ('From' => $from,
              'To' => $to,
              'Subject' => $subject,
              'Content-type' => 'text/html');
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
             'auth' => true,
             'username' => $username,
             'password' => $password));

            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body, $cc);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added in the ability to CC Email addresses in:

```
if(!function_exists("sendemail"))
{
    function sendemail($email_to,$email_from,$email_subject,$email_body,$email_replyto,$cc)
    {
        if(filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

            $from = $email_from;
            $to = $email_to;
            $subject = $email_subject;
            $body = $email_body;

            $host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
            $username = "sending@domain.co.uk";
            $password = "*******";

            $headers = array ('From' => $from,
              'To' => $to,
              'Cc' => $cc,
              'Subject' => $subject,
              'Content-type' => 'text/html');
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
             'auth' => true,
             'username' => $username,
             'password' => $password));

            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body, $cc);
        }
    }
}
```

but it only seems to add the CC'd email address(es) into the header and not send the email. it only sends the email to the address in the $email_to variable

Any ideas how i can get the CC working?

Comment: What does the method `send()` do?  If it merely calls PHP's built-in `mail()` I would expect this to work (the CC just has to be in the headers), but if it does something more complex we could only guess at it.

Comment: im guessing it sends the email - im unsure as this function i found somewhere online

Comment: But if you have the class, you have the source. Please post its source.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski pretty sure he is using the Pear class... http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the Pear class `Mail`, If not disregard.

According to this (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php#2073) you need to have the email address you want to cc to in the `receipients` and the `headers`. I personally have never used this code so I can't attest to whether it works or not.

Here is another link saying the same thing: http://raamdev.com/2008/adding-cc-recipients-with-pear-mail/

Pulled from link:

```
$to = 'to@example.com';
$cc = 'cc@example.com';
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc;
$headers['From']    = 'from@example.com';
$headers['To']      = $to;
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';
$headers['Cc']      = 'cc@example.com';
$headers['Reply-To'] = 'from@example.com';

$send = $mail->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

Also just in case you ever need it according to the link to BCC you simply add an email address to the `$recipients` and don't add it to the `$headers`.